# Is it possible in android to keep BLE scanning on a seperate thread so that UI thread is not affected?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

My android app is scanning for BLE devices the whole time. It is slowing down the UI. Is it possible to have the ble scanning on another thread? Working with  Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat devices.

Comment: sure. You can. You just implement it normally as any background works( making HTTP request, playing audio file).

Comment: I'm doing the scanning inside a service. Communicating with UI via BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: You can use several approaches such as : Service, or Thread + Handler. They can handle background tasks and update UI on main thread

Comment: @QuangNguyen A service runs on the UI thread.  You'd have to use Service+ a thread to move it off the UI thread.

Comment: ble scan **has** to run on the background thread. I can't imagine how you made it run onUI. Show your code.

Comment: Ble scanning is happening in a service and inside a thread. But when the scanning is happening continuously the UI sometimes stops responding. It looks like the parsing and processing part is running on the main thread to avoid data mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the Android team changed the behaviour in Lollipop so that all scan callbacks are always posted on the main thread (hardcoded), so no it's not possible to use another thread. You can of course post the work yourself to another thread when you handle the event (from the main thread) to reduce the amount of work done on the main thread.